# Flatten and distinct multiple arrays in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, vuex

I have the following object:

```
'1': {
   id: 1,
   ...
   tags: ['cat I', 'cat II']
 },
'2': {
   id: 2,
   tags: ['cat II', 'cat III']
 }
```

To get all the categories ( but no duplicates ) I do the following:

```
  const cats = [];
  this.courses.forEach(data => (data.tags) ? cats.push(data.tags) : '');
  return [...new Set(cats.flat())];
```

It works but I have the feeling this is way to "over the top". It's also runs twice because its in the computed properties.

Is there a beter way to distinct & filter out the categories. Maybe by giving a query to the store?

Comment: do you have an array or an object

Comment: can you show the result you want?

Comment: Just directly add them to a set? Also, instead of `forEach` with a conditional operator, consider `filter` -> `map` or alternatively `reduce`.

Comment: The syntax of your input is pretty off. You're missing a `'` delimiter, and the second object has only one item in `tags` (a string containing `,`). Can you fix the syntax and check if that's *really* what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` to get an array of tags. You can use destructuring and defaults to get the `tags` property, or assign an empty array if it's missing. To get unique tags, create a Set from the array of tags, and spread the Set back to an array:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"tags":["cat I","cat II"]},{"id":2,"tags":["cat II","cat III"]},{"id":3}]

const result = [...new Set(data.flatMap(({ tags = [] }) => tags))]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Look thats what I call clean. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ```Array.reduce()``` as well, but I find this much cleaner. In case you want to explore more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 1):

You do:

```js
const courses = [{id: 1, tags: ['cat I', 'cat II ']}, {id: 2, tags: ['cat II', 'cat III']}, {id: 3}]

const tags = courses
  .reduce((a, { tags = [] }) => [...a, ...tags], [])
  .map(tag => tag.trim()) // <-- to remove extra spaces in "cat II "
  
const result = [...new Set(tags)]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `[...a, ...tags]` I personally prefer a simple `a.concat(tags)`. It looks less like a really indecisive piece of code.